# Who decides on the job offer salary?

Tags: software-industry, salary, job-offer, software-development, europe

I recently interviewed at a software development company (~300 employees) and they have called me to come again when they will give me an offer.

I interviewed with a HR person and the team lead, and then had a technical interview with a couple of members of the team.

I would like to get some insight into the process behind deciding on the job offer. Who determines the details of the offer, the salary etc.? Is it the HR person that interviewed me, the team lead, someone else from management? Does the team also play a part? Anyways, you get the idea what I'm interested in.

All information "from the other side" is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello there, what goal do you seek in finding about that?

Comment: I don't have a particular goal, I'm just curious. I'd just like to have more insight into the decision process.

Comment: It really depends on the company. Smaller companies will have entirely different policies from larger companies.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Well I think a goal I had in mind was to know better who I'm negotiating with. Would that make the post on topic? I'll edit if so. Otherwise, feel free to close it.

Comment: @user102611 The point here, you don't need to know the "who" part. It's an overall organization decision, based on organizational policies and requirement. It's entirely possible for some "who" to make different calls under different scenario - yes, that's right, the scenario is important, not the who. :)

Answer (score 4):

> Who determines the details of the offer, the salary etc.?

The answer does varies organization to organization. Generally it's the hiring manager (the person you report to or eventually report to) that you are negotiating with for your salary, signing bonus, relocation, title, etc, but the manager may be constrained by their budget and other company policies such as pay bands for certain levels and titles that are typically set by HR.

You may end up negotiating with someone who's more senior than your manager. I interviewed in a team where all salary negotiation went through the senior directory of engineering even though I ended up reporting to the engineering manager (senior director of engineering > director of engineering > engineering manager).

A recruiter typically serves as a buffer between you and the hiring manager helping coordinate details of your interview and may sometimes negotiate salary to a certain degree. If you want more than the recruiter is authorized to give, you would have to negotiate with the hiring manager. If you want more money than the HR guidelines, a manager may have to go through and request an exception or request a change in your title. I once requested a government organization match a private company's salary offer. While the hiring manager agreed to try to match, the salary match was eventually rejected by HR, because it violated the pay band for my level.

> Does the team also play a part?

No. The team typically only will advise hire or no hire and sometimes what level is appropriate (entry-level, senior, staff, etc) for the candidate. The team does not know what the individual's salary nor do they participate in the salary negotiation.

Answer (score 1):

While it is impossible to say what exactly would happen in your case, in my experience (both from being recruited and hiring), it is a combination of HR and the line manager.

There will typically be a set of terms and conditions that any role needs to adhere to. On top of that most medium-large companies have established salary bands that go with the job grades.

Standard practice in some companies is for new hires to join at the bottom of the relevant salary band.

While this may seem to be cast in stone a little, you actually have more sway than you think. If you are lucky enough to land the role, there may be things you can tweak if you're not entirely happy with them. In one role for example, I asked for more pay and in another, I asked for slightly different hours.

Some people are of course reluctant to upset the apple cart by asking for preferable terms when they haven't even started the job yet, but it has to be a good fit on both sides. There is nothing worse than starting a new job feeling underpaid and taken advantage of.